# Cannot connect to eth0 using static configuration

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

My router broke, so I am trying to set up a wired connection using eth0. I am using Crunchbang Waldorf, which is Debian based.

I put the correct settings in /etc/network/interfaces and I also created an entry in Network Manager. The problem is that when I plug in the wire, I can only connect to Auto Ethernet using the Network Manager GUI. If I try connecting to that and then modifying the settings for Auto Ethernet from the NM, then the NM closes the connection. When I connect to Auto Ethernet again, the NM creates another entry for Auto Ethernet with the wrong (default) settings, and connects using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to connect without Network Manager? It is very easy: as sudo,

```
  service network-manager stop
  ip link set eth0 down
  ip addr flush dev eth0
  ip link set dev eth0 up
  dhclient -v eth0
```

and when you get a proper reply, you need to add DNS nameservers,

```
  echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf
  echo nameserver 8.8.4.4 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

and to add a default route: assuming your router has IP address 192.168.1.1,

```
  ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

If the router has a different IP, replace 192.168.1.1 with the real one. For instance, in general if your LAN net is 192.168.191.0/24, the router will be 192.168.191.1 or 192.168.191.254.

All of this can be easily scripted, and when done you can restart the network manager with

```
   service network-manager start
```